# Show/hide elements in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a comment section on my application that I am ng-repeat-ing over. I am trying to account for a scenario where there are a large amount of comments. My thought was to hide all the comments except for a few and then make a link at the bottom of the comment section that said "More Comments(total)". When the user clicked more comments, it would display the rest of the ng-repeat items.

So far, I've been able to hide the remaining comments by simply saying ng-show="$index < 3" but I haven't come up with a way to display more after the user clicks 'More comments'. I am stuck on how to ng-show on more than one parameter. I had originally thought I could use ng-click to set a variable to true and then use it as a second parameter to ng-show, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-show="$index < 3 || showMore"> {{ comment }}</li>
</ul>
<a ng-click="showMore">More Comments(25)</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me

https://jsfiddle.net/hqqpj9xw/

Although with your current technique you are unnecessarily adding all the comments to the dom and watching them. A more efficient solution would be to use the `limitTo` filter.

```
<div ng-app ng-init="comments = [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div ng-repeat="item in comments | limitTo:showMore ? comments.length : 3">
        comment
    </div>
    <button ng-click="showMore = true">show more</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zrw6dfgc/1/

Comment: Awesome - this works perfectly! Must've had a typo or something in my original, but the limitTo filter is even better.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I've tryied to make my button toggle button adding ng-click"showMore ? false: true" but it didn't work